# Inverse of $f(x)=4x-x^2; x≥2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just asked a question a few minutes ago, but I stumbled upon another one.

This is the question:

Find the inverse of $f(x)=4x-x^2,$ where the domain is $x≥2.
$
I did:

$x=4y-y^2$

$y^2-4y+x=0$

I am stuck here.

Comment: hi and welcome to the site. please learn mathjax. it will increase the chances for good answers

Comment: I have edited the question, please look at my edit and approve it if the format looks better.

Comment: $y=4x-x^2=-(x-2)^2+4 \iff x-2 = \pm \sqrt{4-y}\,$, then use the condition $\,x \ge 2\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll not provide the whole answer, but a slight hint as you prefer.

The equation $y^2-4y+x=0$ is in quadratic form, which you probably know if you are taking Algebra 2, so think of $y$ as a constant term.

**Spoiler (don't hover unless you're stuck):**

> You obtain $y=2±\sqrt{4-x}$ after you use the formula $\frac{-b/2±\sqrt{(-b/2)^2-ac}}{a}.$

I think you can figure out the domain of $f^{-1}(x)$, as the $x$ and $y$ values of f(x) become the $y$ and $x$ values of $f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: May I know why this was downvoted?

Comment: I didn't even think of it like this!

Comment: Ok, I learnt mathjax, why did you use the formula $\frac{-b/2±\sqrt{(-b/2)^2-ac}}{a}$ instead of the normal quadratic formula?

Comment: There is no such thing as the "normal" quadratic formula, and this formula I used works better if the $b$ coefficient is even. To derive the formula, just divide both numerator and denominator of the original formula by 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the inverse by completing the square for y $$y^2-4y=-x$$
$$y^2-4y+4=4-x$$
$$(y-2)^2=4-x$$
$$y=\sqrt{4-x} +2$$
So we get $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{4-x}+2$.  Note, it has to be positive square root, not negative, since the restriction on x of the original function is $x\geq2$.